# how can I send table's values to server in jquery

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have a table which has rows that they can be added or deleted. my question is after adding or removing tr's, how can I send it to server?

```
<form id="tbl_form">
  <table>
    <tr><td>sprots</td><td>need ball?</td><td>yes</td><td>like vollyball</td><i class="fa fa-times"></i></tr>
    <tr><td>sprots</td><td>need ball?</td><td>like swimming</td><i class="fa fa-times"></i></tr>
.
.
  </table>
  <button type="submit" id="btn_submit">submit</button>
</form>

<script>
    $('table').on('click','.fa.fa-times',function(){
       $(this).closest('tr').remove(); 
    });
</script>
```

what I want to get at server-side is something like below:

```
array[0]=sports->need ball?->yes->like vollyball
array[1]=sports->need ball?->swimming->null
```

Comment: Sorry, why don't you use ***form action*** elements?

Comment: Also you say "`ball?->swimming->null`" where's the *"like"* disappeared?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan. default is the current page.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan. I want to show the the length of the value might be different.

Comment: To delete surely all you need to send is row id or whatever your unique database index field is? As for `add` how are you actually adding rows ? Doe suser edit right in row or is there another form somewhere such as in a modal?

Comment: Perhaps your `<i>` should be inside a `<td>`?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#btn_submit').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var dataFromTable = [];

  // get data from table:
  $("table tr").each(function(){
    var row = []

    $(this).find("td").each(function(){
      var tdText = $(this).text();
      row.push( tdText );
    });

    dataFromTable.push(row);
  });


  // send data to server:
  var dataString=JSON.stringify(dataFromTable);
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "server.php",
    dataType:'json',
    data: {"dataString": dataString},
    success: function(msg){
      console.log("send to server successfully", msg);
    }
  });

  console.log(dataFromTable);


  /**
    on the server side:

    $dataString = $_POST["dataString"];
    $data = json_decode($dataString); // data as array

  **/

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="tbl_form">
  <table>
    <tr><td>sprots</td><td>need ball?</td><td>yes</td><td>like vollyball</td><i class="fa fa-times"></i></tr>
    <tr><td>sprots</td><td>need ball?</td><td>like swimming</td><i class="fa fa-times"></i></tr>
    .
    .
  </table>
  <button type="submit" id="btn_submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: how can I insert the dataFormTable into a `input type='hidden'`

Comment: I don't see any reason for this. However, `var dataString=JSON.stringify(dataFromTable);  $(".yourInputField").val( dataString );`